# Why does SignalR client ConnectionState not change when I shut down the site and then restart?

Tags: c#, iis, signalr

I host the signalR client in IIS as a web site.
And I tested send message from server to this client, it works ok.

Then **I shutdown the client site, and restart it after 10 mins**.

Again, I send a message to this client, it still works.

My question is **why the connection state didn't change**?

BTW, I have state change event callback method

```
connection.StateChanged += (x) => {
    OnStateChange(connectionId, x);
};

private void OnStateChange(string connectionId, StateChange stateChange)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    text.Append("ConnectiId：").Append(connectionId).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    text.Append("OldState：").Append(stateChange.OldState.ToString()).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    text.Append("NewState：").Append(stateChange.NewState.ToString()).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    if(stateChange.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
    {
        //reconnect
    }
    Util.Log("signalR_statechange", text.ToString(), false);
}
```

There are no logs when I shutdown or restart the site.

Answer (score 0):

go to this thread read...the below Continuation ...also there is no need onstatechange event... read msdn link it will more help for [you](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server)

How to handle connection lifetime events in the Hub class

Typical reasons for handling connection lifetime events are to keep track of whether a user is connected or not, and to keep track of the association between user names and connection IDs. To run your own code when clients connect or disconnect, override the OnConnected, OnDisconnected, and OnReconnected virtual methods of the Hub class, as shown in the following example.

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, record the association between
        // the current connection ID and user name, and mark the user as online.
        // After the code in this method completes, the client is informed that
        // the connection is established; for example, in a JavaScript client,
        // the start().done callback is executed.
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, mark the user as offline, 
        // delete the association between the current connection id and user name.
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        // Add your own code here.
        // For example: in a chat application, you might have marked the
        // user as offline after a period of inactivity; in that case 
        // mark the user as online again.
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

When OnConnected, OnDisconnected, and OnReconnected are called

Each time a browser navigates to a new page, a new connection has to be established, which means SignalR will execute the OnDisconnected method followed by the OnConnected method. SignalR always creates a new connection ID when a new connection is established.

The OnReconnected method is called when there has been a temporary break in connectivity that SignalR can automatically recover from, such as when a cable is temporarily disconnected and reconnected before the connection times out. The OnDisconnected method is called when the client is disconnected and SignalR can't automatically reconnect, such as when a browser navigates to a new page. Therefore, a possible sequence of events for a given client is OnConnected, OnReconnected, OnDisconnected; or OnConnected, OnDisconnected. You won't see the sequence OnConnected, OnDisconnected, OnReconnected for a given connection.

The OnDisconnected method doesn't get called in some scenarios, such as when a server goes down or the App Domain gets recycled. When another server comes on line or the App Domain completes its recycle, some clients may be able to reconnect and fire the OnReconnected event.

For more information, see Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR.

Caller state not populated

The connection lifetime event handler methods are called from the server, which means that any state that you put in the state object on the client will not be populated in the Caller property on the server. For information about the state object and the Caller property, see How to pass state between clients and the Hub class later in this topic.

How to get information about the client from the Context property

To get information about the client, use the Context property of the Hub class. The Context property returns a HubCallerContext object which provides access to the following information:

The connection ID of the calling client.

```
string connectionID = Context.ConnectionId;
```

The connection ID is a GUID that is assigned by SignalR (you can't specify the value in your own code). There is one connection ID for each connection, and the same connection ID is used by all Hubs if you have multiple Hubs in your application.

Comment: But this article still does not explain why the client did not reconnect or disconnect after I shutdown IIS site

Comment: you need to add cookie for client browser in the client connect id then only

Comment: you identified which user is connected in system on system connected event.. and store the all chat is local db

Answer (score 0):

the reason is:

did you close the client browser after shut down the iis?

I can tell you that the client is still connecting even if you shut down the iis.

because the signalr client html file not necessary hosted in iis, it can connect even it is hosted in the client side.

Comment: It's not a html page. My signalR client is started in Global.asax.

Comment: so did you close the browser?  it's should be still connecting when browser not closed